# PJLIB_UTIL_EDNSNOWORKINGNS issue in pjsip

Tags: objective-c, pjsip, ipv4, pjsua2

Using PJSIP library version 2.7.2

Issue : Outgoing call for specific iPV6 provider

```
pjsua_call_make_call(the_acc_id, &uri, &call_opt, NULL, NULL, &call_id)
```

Error Log

```
10:XX.16.XXX           pjsua_core.c  ..Trying STUN server test2.XXXXXX.ca IPv4 (1 of 1)..
10:XX.16.XXX           pjsua_core.c  ..Error starting STUN socket for test2.XXXXXX.ca: No working DNS nameserver (PJLIB_UTIL_EDNSNOWORKINGNS)
10:XX.16.XXX           pjsua_core.c  ..STUN resolution failed: No working DNS nameserver (PJLIB_UTIL_EDNSNOWORKINGNS)
10:XX.16.XXX           pjsua_core.c  ..Ignoring STUN resolution failure (by setting)
10:XX.16.XXX          pjsua_media.c  ..RTP socket reachable at 169.XXX.XXX.XXX:40XX
10:XX.16.XXX          pjsua_media.c  ..RTCP socket reachable at 169.XXX.XXX.XXX:40XY
10:XX.16.XXX           pjsua_core.c  ..Trying STUN server test2.XXXXXX.ca IPv4 (1 of 1)..
10:XX.16.XXX           pjsua_core.c  ..Error starting STUN socket for test2.XXXXXX.ca: No working DNS nameserver (PJLIB_UTIL_EDNSNOWORKINGNS)
10:XX.16.XXX           pjsua_core.c  ..STUN resolution failed: No working DNS nameserver (PJLIB_UTIL_EDNSNOW


10:XX.16.XXX           pjsua_core.c  ..Ignoring STUN resolution failure (by setting)
10:XX.16.XXX         pjsua_media.c  ..RTP socket reachable at 169.XXX.XXX.XXX:40XY
10:XX.16.XXX          pjsua_media.c  ..RTCP socket reachable at 169.XXX.XXX.XXX:40XZ
10:XX.16.XXX          pjsua_media.c  ..Media index 0 selected for audio call 0
10:XX.16.XXX         sip_resolve.c  ....Failed to resolve 'test2.XXXXXX.ca'. Err=320046 (No working DNS nameserver (PJLIB_UTIL_EDNSNOWORKINGNS))
10:XX.16.XXX         tsx0x1041970a8  ....Failed to send Request msg INVITE/cseq=5627 (tdta0x1038c34a8)! err=320046 (No working DNS nameserver (PJLIB_UTIL_EDNSNOWORKINGNS))
10:XX.16.XXX                   pj.m  .......Call 0 state=DISCONNCTD
10:XX.16.XXX          pjsua_media.c  .......Call 0: deinitializing media..
10:XX.16.XXX          pjsua_media.c  ........Call 0: cleaning up provisional media, prov_med_cnt=2, med_cnt=0
10:XX.16.XXX          pjsua_media.c  .Call 0: deinitializing media..
10:XX.16.XXX          pjsua_media.c



10:XX.16.XXX                   pj.m  Error making call: No working DNS nameserver (PJLIB_UTIL_EDNSNOWORKINGNS) [status=320046]
10:XX.16.XXX            pjsua_aud.c  Closing sound device after idle for 1 second(s)
10:XX.16.XXX            pjsua_aud.c  .Closing iPhone IO device sound playback device and iPhone IO device sound capture device
10:XX.16.XXX        coreaudio_dev.c  .core audio stream stopped
```

Comment: Why is this tagged ipv6?

Comment: Again, why is this tagged ipv6? There is nothing about IPv6 in your log. It's all IPv4. And I can resolve test2.XXXXXX.ca just fine; it's 103.224.182.239. But are you connecting to a different IP?

Comment: @MichaelHampton thank you for the reply. The issue is we have ipv4 on server side and on client side we have ipv6. So we want to convert the ipv6 to ipv4 in pjsip side and send it to server so that we can connect.